# String to char array conversion

Tags: arduino-mega, programming

In my project I need to convert a string to a char array. From various examples I concluded that `toCharArray()` will convert a string to a char array. But I failed to do so. The error is:

> 'a' does not name a type

The code I am using is:

```
String a = "45317";
char b[6];
a.toCharArray(b,6);
```

Resources are https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray and http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=199362.0

Comment: maybe this example may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68497443/convert-an-arduino-c-string-to-an-ansi-c-string-char-array-using-the-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to use a method of `a` in the global scope, that's doomed to failure. You can only call methods within functions.

If all you want is a char array with "45317" in it then just use:

```
char *b = "45317";
```

If you want to convert a string that is built at runtime into a char array, then your current method is correct - you just have to do it in the right place.

Answer (score 4):

There's a built in conversion which will return the underlying string-contents as a NULL terminated character array:

```
 String foo = "Steve was here"
 char *text = foo.c_str();
```

That is probably all you need, unless you do want to copy into a buffer.  In that case you can use the standard C library to do that:

```
 // Declare a buffer
 char buf[100];

 // Copy this string into it
 String foo = "This is my string"
 snprintf( buf, sizeof(buf)-1, "%s", foo.c_str() );

 // Ensure we're terminated
 buf[sizeof(buf)] = '\0';
```

(You might prefer `strcpy`, `memcpy`, etc to `snprintf`.)

Comment: 1) `c_str()` is no replacement for `toCharArray()`: your first example fails to compile with “_error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’_”. Of course, if you only need a `const char *`, then `c_str()` is to be preferred. 2) In terms of code size, `snprintf()` is a very inefficient way of copying a string. 3) No need to subtract one from `sizeof(buf)` in the second argument to `snprintf()`.